# Need help using @apply directive in Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I found the @apply directive an easy way to reuse code but when I'm using the @apply directive in tailwind css it is showing me error You cannot `@apply` the `btn` utility here because it creates a circular dependency.

This is my HTML code

```
            <a class="bg-transparent border btn border-black hover:bg-black hover:text-white px-6 py-2 rounded-2xl"
                href="">Browse</a>
            <a>Look</a>
```

I want the classes of the 1st a tag in my second tag by just using @apply directive

And this is my tailwind css file where I put the @apply directive

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;

.btn{
@apply bg-transparent border btn border-black hover:bg-black hover:text-white px-6 py-2 rounded-2xl;
}
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error keeps showing because you added the `btn` class inside itself in your CSS file

your HTML should be like this:

```
<a class="btn" href="">Browse</a>

<a>Look</a>
```

and your CSS should be like this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
.btn{
@apply bg-transparent border  border-black hover:bg-black hover:text-white px-6 py-2 rounded-2xl;
}
@tailwind utilities;
```

also, it's a better practice to add your components with `@layer components` so you can add new components classes wherever  you want and not only between `@tailwind components;` and `@tailwind utilities;`

**Better practice**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components{
  .btn{
      @apply bg-transparent border  border-black hover:bg-black hover:text-white px-6 py-2 rounded-2xl;
    }
}
```

see the example on [tailwind PLAY](https://play.tailwindcss.com/8xLdxyjOC5)

Comment: This causes "You cannot `@apply` the `invisible` utility here because it creates a circular dependency" in an Angular application.

Comment: @JanBrus same in nextjs. We cant use `@apply` inside `@layer components`